# How to make Sublime JSON syntax warn on extra comma

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

This is for how my sublime text look like when I edit a JSON file:

[image]

I want that sublime will alert me when there are too many commas (like nodejs `json.parse`)

[image]

I need it because some JSON parser thinks that this JSON file is not valid.

Comment: The Sublime text 3 extension [`JsFormat`](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) has an option called *eval_code*. Maybe this is what you want. But I haven't tested it yet

Comment: That character is a comma `,` not a semicolon `;` - I updated your question.

Comment: May you explain about eval_code and how it is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Sublime Text plugins, your best resource is the Package Control [search](https://packagecontrol.io/search) functionality. A search for [`json lint`](https://packagecontrol.io/search/json%20lint) turns up [`SublimeLinter-json`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-json), which **must** be used in conjunction with [`SublimeLinter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter), which only works on Sublime Text 3. Please read *all* of the documentation linked at the above pages, as both SublimeLinter and the SublimeLinter-json plugin must be manually set up to work with your system. It uses Sublime's internal JSON parser, which in turn is based on Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html) module, modified to accept `//` and `/* ... */` comments in `.sublime_settings` files.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that python JSON module, is not like node JSON.parse module. NodeJS not accept comments or extra comments in JSON.

Comment: You are right. JSONLint it is exactly like JSON.parse syntax!